# If the Torah tells you not to add or subtract, what does it imply for behaviour?

Tags: mathematics

If the Torah forbids addition and subtraction, what does it imply for Jews, and for ultra orthodox jews, regarding practical life? It is a baffling rule.

Can you you use money at all? can you not subtract change?

Can you use a clock to count the hours of the day? i.e. doing something in quarter of an hour.

Can you number the pages of a book?

Can you count the difference in age between members of your family?

Is it not a rule that is followed in modern life? so what does it imply theologically? Who should comply by the rule and who shouldn't?

Comment: Oh boy. If you are basing this on [What does Judaism think of math?](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/55251/5151) and answers to that question, note that it is "Purim Torah" and not meant to be taken seriously (at all). As an answer below states, the verse that says not to add or subtract is referring to commandments, not numbers.

Answer (score 6):

This might refer to Deut. 4:2. There is the advice not add or remove *commands*.

http://ohr.edu/this_week/its_not_quite_that_simple/5926

So associating this advice with maths and numbers might actually remove the context. Or in other words: This might add somthing by substracting.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks for your answer. Hope you stick around. :)